# Express - Promise pending when loop queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I receive an array with several data and i have to make a query for each element of array. But this was give me a `promise pending`. How ca i solve that?
What is the problem?

```
       getFamilies(req, res)
      {
        console.log(req.params.data);
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(req.params.data);
        var compounds = parsedData[0].compounds;
        var supplier = parsedData[0].supplier;
        var families = parsedData[0].families;
        console.log(parsedData[0].compounds.length);

        var parts = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < compounds.length; i++)
        {
          console.log(families[i]);
          console.log("SELECT u_part.u_idpart, u_part.u_order, u_part.u_familia, st.fornecedor, st.design, st.ref FROM u_part INNER JOIN st ON u_part.u_familia = st.familia WHERE st.fornecedor ='" + supplier +"' and u_part.u_familia="+ families[i]);
          parts.push(request.query("SELECT u_part.u_idpart, u_part.u_order, u_part.u_familia, st.fornecedor, st.design, st.ref FROM u_part INNER JOIN st ON u_part.u_familia = st.familia WHERE st.fornecedor ='" + supplier +"' and u_part.u_familia="+ families[i]));
        }

        return Promise.all([parts]).then(function(listOfResults)
        {
            console.log(listOfResults[0]);
          console.log("done");
        }).catch(function(err)
        {
            // ... query error checks
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where in that code do you get "promise pending"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises, which `parts` already is, not an array of arrays of promises (`[parts]`). Use

```
return Promise.all( parts ).then…
//                 ^     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

`.then` returns a promise so you need do stuff in the `.then` and not return it.

```
Promise.all([parts]).then(listOfResults => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(listOfResults)) //for example
}, err => {
  res.send(500, JSON.stringify(err)); // for example
});
```