# xhttp GET request to an express.js server - nothing returned

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to do a simple xhttp GET request to an express.js server. Unfortunately I get no response data with this code. The connection is fine as I have successfully used "`res.send`" to send a body back from the server.

I am not sure if my use of "`findOne`" on the server is incorrect or if my use of xhttp on the client is incorrect. I suspect it is the client.

I'd appreciate any advice.

*** CLIENT CODE ***

```
function getfood() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/clientfood", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

*** SERVER CODE - Express.js / Node ***

```
app.get('/clientfood', cors(), (req, res) => { 
  //res.send('test'); //this works at least
  db.collection('quotes').findOne({
     "_id": ObjectId("12345")
  },
  {
    name: 1,
    quote: 1
  })
})
```

Comment: What `findOne` returns? A `Promise`?

Comment: i mean... i don't see where you're sending response data or reading response data...

Comment: Please specify which exact database you are using?

Comment: Questions title says `nothing returned`.  In the code you do not have a `return` statement.  Hmm I wonder what the problem could be?  Oh well, I guess we will never know.  Its just too hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

> xhttp GET request to an express.js server - nothing returned

Your server code does not return a response.  You need to do something like `res.send(...)` or `res.json(...)` to return a response back to the caller and you need to do that in the callback that your database provides for communicating back the result of a query (in most DBs, you can either use a plain callback or a promise).

Your client code does not listen for a response.  Example for how to do that shown [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and would typically be:

```
function getfood() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.addEventListener("load", function() {
        if (xhttp.status === 200) {
            // have data in xhttp.responseText, process it here
        } else {
            // got some other response here
        }
    });
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/clientfood", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: @jogoeire - If this answered your question or led you to an answer, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most.  This will also earn you some reputation points on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much - especially @jfriend00. I have a lot to learn about how these frameworks work. After taking your advice about SEND I had a little trouble seeing the result on my frontend. I got the message "promise pending". I fixed that with the code suggested in this post. 
[Express - Promise pending when loop queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576504/express-promise-pending-when-loop-queries)
Also I modified my findOne function to grab the entire object for my id.

Final code:

```
    app.get('/clientfood', cors(), (req, res) => {   
mydata = db.collection('quotes').findOne(
{
"_id": ObjectId("12345")   
})
// promise code
Promise.all([mydata]).then(listOfResults => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(listOfResults)) //for example
}, err => {
  res.send(500, JSON.stringify(err)); // for example
});

})
```